# Where can I find wood?

Tags: starbound

I started up a new world and all the nearby trees I've cut down have only given me plant fibres.

All there other sources of wood, as I need wood to make many of the basic items.

Comment: Are you chopping the trees down with an axe, or just using your fists? [The wiki says you need to use an axe.](http://starbounder.org/Unrefined_Wood)

Comment: @Wipqozn Chopping the trees isn't a problem, and I'm actually using the matter manipulator to do it. Would be nice if I had an axe but again, need wood for those :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an axe or the multitool you start with to chop down trees, simply aim at the base of the tree and chop away.

bare in mind that some planets might not have trees or trees that produce wood (which is what you are experiencing). You could explore that planet a bit further to find trees or just jump to a different planet.  A little bit of coal gathered from the surface will allow you to jump planets.

Comment: I'm on the starting planet though so I don't have any fuel to travel. I didn't have much time to explore too far to the sides (or the equipment for that matter). Hopefully those trees aren't too far away then.

Comment: @Katustrawfic Actually if you've gathered any coal, you DO have fuel.  A single piece of coal will get you to another planet.  Yes, spaceships run off of coal.

Comment: @Zibbobz Huh, I expected fuel to be... "fuel". I shall try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find wood on (at least some) planets by cutting down trees. Be sure to use the Matter Manipulator that makes a beam of light appear to the block you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Look around more for wood or use your matter manipulator to dig and fuel coal. Then use the coal for fuel to travel to another planet.